# Localizing gives strange behavior, please advice

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, nsstring

Hmmm, I'm not so clever as I thought I was.
Struggling all day with a few lines of code.

```
char latChar = (actLat > 0) ? 'N' : 'S';
NSString *latString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c" , latChar];    
NSString *latStringLocal = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"%c",nil), latString];
```

In the first line: wich character is the correct one. Latitude > 0 degrees it's N, < 0 it is a S. This works.
In the second line I'm converting the char to a string. Works OK too.
In the third line all of it went wrong. When running the app all kind of symbol and normal characters are shown. Every second a new one.
That last part is understandable because the locationmanager is constant updating.

But why those characters? What am I doiing wrong here? See both localizable.strings files

en.lproj

```
"N" = "N";
"S" = "S";
"W" = "W"; 
"E" = "E";
```

nl.proj

```
"N" = "N";
"S" = "Z";
"W" = "W";
"E" = "O";
```

The app displayname works fine so the .strings file is found en "read".
Please advice. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've no idea what you are doing with `NSLocalizedString()`; the first argument should be `@"N"`, `@"S"` and not `@"%c"`.

Comment: @ trojanfoe Thanks for your reply. I want to show the characters of latitude and longitude localized. So I tried to put a placeholder in and read the value from a variable (latChar in this case).

Comment: Stupid me, I put my keys in the InfoPlist.strings file instead of in the Localized.strings file. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

I would write it like this:

```
NSString *latStringLocal = actLat > 0 ? NSLocalizedString(@"N", @"North abbreviation") : NSLocalizedString(@"S", @"South abbreviation");
```

Then regenerate the English strings:

```
find . -name \*.m | xargs genstrings
```

en.lproj/Localizable.strings will contain:

```
/* North abbreviation */
"N" = "N";

/* South abbreviation */
"S" = "S";
```

…and nl.lproj/Localizable.strings should contain:

```
/* North abbreviation */
"N" = "N";

/* South abbreviation */
"S" = "Z";
```

Note that *genstrings* utility does not like variable parameters to NSLocalizedString (won't generate a key for it). But at run time - if the key exists in `[NSBundle.mainBundle localizedStringForKey:(key) value:@"" table:nil]` - all should work.

Comment: Stupid me, I put my keys in the InfoPlist.strings file instead of in the Localized.strings file. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score -1):

```
NSString *latStringLocal =  NSLocalizedString((actLat > 0) ? @"N" : @"Y", @"");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, put your answer in my code, it compiles correct. However it shows me the English characters in a Dutch device. Any suggestions?

Comment: Silly enough, the dutch nib is loading correctly and the localized app displyname is shown. So, I  don't know what to think of it.

Comment: any other texts is localizable? You can see dutch language in standard components?

Comment: hm... try this: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial make sure that you did anything else correct

Comment: Already read up ont Ray's tutorial, I can't see that I've made more mistakes. I will look into it again. Thank you for now.

Comment: About your former comment, I work with a localized XIB file and those test are correct in the Dutch language.

Comment: to make sure that this code is ok, try to simply set somewhere: self.someLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"SOME LOCALIZED STRIND TEST", @""); if this is also will not localizable then you need to look somewhere else, for example in the way you generated and added you .lpoj files

Comment: FYI, I changed the keys to North, South, West and east in my .m file and in the .strings file. It compiles ok, but right now I get the full words displayed. So basically it looks likes it reads the keys instaed of the values. Any  suggestions?

Comment: This error pops up: InfoPlist.strings:0: error: read failed: The data couldn’t be read because it has been corrupted.

Comment: try to remove old localization files and regenerate you new with genstrings

Comment: Stupid me, I put my keys in the InfoPlist.strings file instead of in the Localized.strings file. Thank you for your reply and all your help!